# CosmosClient vs DocumentClient

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What's the difference between [CosmosClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-java) and [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-java-application), in Java. Should I prefer one over the other, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, `CosmosClient` is part of new SDK for Azure Cosmos DB SQL API while `DocumentClient` is part of the old SDK (when Cosmos DB SQL API was called DocumentDB).

Old SDK Github Repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java

New SDK Github Repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos

Other big difference is the the new SDK supports both `async` and `sync` whereas the older SDK only supports `sync`.

Considering the old SDK has not been updated in quite some time, the recommendation would be to use the newer one.

Comment: Here is a blog post on our new Java SDK. This is in preview now. Should go GA around BUILD. Definitely recommend v4 for new projects. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/java-sdk-v4-1/

Comment: Thanks Gaurav and Mark